# SQL Query JOIN syntax

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following tables and would like to query one more element from them.

```
categories table ->idcat(int), cat(varchar); 
topics table     ->idtopic(int), topic(varchar), idcat(int-fk), iduser(int-fk); 
replies table    ->idreply(int), reply(varchar) iduser(int-fk), idtopic(int-fk)
users table      ->iduser(int), username(varchar).
```

My current query is;

```
$query = "SELECT t.topic, t.idtopic, u.username
    FROM topics t
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat
    LEFT JOIN users u ON t.iduser = u.iduser
    WHERE c.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'";
```

Which presents 'Topic' and 'Username'.  I'd like to show 'idReply' as well but don't know the proper JOIN syntax.

Comment: Won't there be multiple fields in `replies` for each topic?

Comment: I would think there could be with this table structure. So you've got the potential to return multiple rows with a new join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t.topic, 
    t.idtopic, 
    u.username
FROM 
    topics t 
LEFT JOIN 
    categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON t.iduser = u.iduser
LEFT JOIN  // new
    replies r ON r.iduser = u.iduser AND r.idtopic = t.idtopic // new
WHERE c.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'";
```

This will generate a row for every reply to every topic in the specified category. Which could be a lot of records.

You may also want to experiment with the exact type of join on the replies table to get the result you want. LEFT JOIN is probably correct as you'll still get a result if there's no reply to a given topic. This may depend on your flavour of SQL.

`OUTER JOIN` & `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are possibilities.

Using `INNER JOIN` will ensure only topics with replies are returned.

Comment: perhaps add `r.idreply, r.reply` to the select clause?

Comment: That might be useful. You'd be able to add any fields from the 4 tables with this join.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `reply_id` (foreign key) in your `topics` table. After that you can use this query.

```
$query = "SELECT t.topic, t.idtopic, u.username, r.id as reply_id
          FROM topics t
          LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat
          LEFT JOIN users u ON t.iduser = u.iduser
          LEFT JOIN replies r ON t.reply_id = r.id
          WHERE c.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'";
```

Comment: While that might work in a technical sense, I don't think it would help the OP. It would seem you would need/want to have multiple replies to each topic, so it would be better to have the fk in the replies table and join on that like: `LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.idtopic = t.idtopic`

Comment: A `reply_id` on the topic table will enforce a 1:1 relationship between topics and replies. This may in fact be what's required. A `reply_id` would be suitable if this is the case, otherwise look at my answer.